# Change network interface name with systemd.link on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04, udevd

I am trying to set some universal names for the predictable names. I am doing this to be able to have the same interface names on all my machines.

Iam trying to follow "Example 2. /etc/systemd/network/10-dmz.link" from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html

my files look as follows:

/etc/systemd/network/10-dmz.link

```
[Match] 
MACAddress=80:ee:73:f1:01:43

[Link]
Name=dmz0
```

/etc/systemd/network/10-dmz.network

```
[Match] 
Name=dmz0

[Network]

Address=192.168.25.2/24
```

After reboot I do not get an interface called dmz0.
Systemd-networkd is enabled and setting a IP on another interface with a .network file works.

What am I missing?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to have the interface names changed I had to run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot